# Can't read in a XML file using QXML/SAX and C++

Tags: c++, xml, qt, sax

I'm trying to read in a .xml file in QT but every time I do, `QXmlSimpleReader.parse` will return false - see: *qDebug()<< "parse fail";* at the bottom of the *descriptionfilereader* class.

Why is this failing? I have the .xml file in the same folder as the code. (Note: I copied the XML into notepad and saved it as a .xml with ANSI enconding. My computer is also showing the file is an XML document).

Explanation of code: DescriptionFileReader object is created in main and the handler of the reading is done by using an instance of the parser class.

(edit: I have changed the XML document to read in to a simpler one in hopes of finding the problem easier)

Descriptionfilereader.cpp:

```
#include "descriptionfilereader.h"
#include "parser.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <QXml.h>
#include <string>
#include <QXmlDefaultHandler>
using namespace std;

DescriptionFileReader::DescriptionFileReader()
{

}

DescriptionFileReader::~DescriptionFileReader()
{

}



void DescriptionFileReader::Read()
{

Parser handler;
QXmlSimpleReader xmlReader; //Intialize xmlReader

xmlReader.setContentHandler(&handler);
xmlReader.setErrorHandler(&handler);

QFile xmlFile ("notes.xml");

QXmlInputSource source (&xmlFile);

//handler.start     \/ this returns false
bool ok = xmlReader.parse (source); 

if (!ok)
     qDebug()<< "parse fail";

}
```

parser.cpp:

```
#include "parser.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <qstring.h>
#include <qxml.h>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

 using namespace std;

static const char TAG_ITEM[] = "description";
static const char TAG_MATERIAL[]= "Material";
static const char TAG_MOUNT[] = "Mount";
QString currElement_;



bool Parser::characters(const QString& text)
{
    if( currElement_ == TAG_ITEM) {}

    else
      {return false;}
    return true;
}

bool Parser::startElement(const QString&, const QString& localName,
                          const QString& qName,
                          const QXmlAttributes& atts)
{
    if( localName == TAG_ITEM)
    {
        qDebug()<< "It's coming";
    }
    else if( localName == TAG_MATERIAL ) {}
    else if( localName == TAG_MOUNT ){}
    else{return false;}

    currElement_ = localName;
    return true;
}
bool Parser::endElement( const QString&, const QString& localName, const QString& )
{
    if( localName == TAG_ITEM)
    {
        qDebug()<< "It's gone";
    }
    else if( localName == TAG_MATERIAL ) {}
    else if( localName == TAG_MOUNT ){}
    else{return false;}

    currElement_ = localName;

    return true;
}
```

XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: I am not seeing a `</diagram>` tag to close the document

Comment: For some weird reason, </diagram> was in the original code  but didn't show up. I have since changed the XML document I am working with to a simpler one to make locating issues easier.  I have a feeling the issue lies within "QXmlInputSource source (&xmlFile);" because the example code for simplereader is "QXmlInputSource *source = new QXmlInputSource(file);" but everytime I type it out exactly like that, I get an error. Do you know of any examples of what file exactly is? (Is it a QString, QFile, Exact filepath, etc)?